# SonarLint Visual Studio 2015 plugin does not support asp.net core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarlint

My setup:

- Visual Studio 2015 community with the SonarLint plugin (http://www.sonarlint.org/visualstudio/)
- SonarQube 6.1

Problem:

After connecting to sonarqube server I cannot bind to a project because there is no csproj in asp.net core. It refuses to bind to the project because of that

Manually running sonarscanner.bat works

How can this be done without tfs? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected at the moment. The tooling around .NET Core is not yet finished, and SonarLint integrates into the tooling. You may want to follow the development related to this aggregate ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-484

Comment: I'm i right that in order to support .NET Core porting Analyzers to .NET Core required ? I mean it's more technical change, since all the logic for .NET framework is already there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Also, porting the analyzers is not such a big deal, however the Scanner for MsBuild is not trivial.